# Moving from HTTP to HTTPS on Laravel behind CloudFlare

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cloudflare

I have a application made on laravel 5.2.
It was running fine on HTTP.

I used `asset` function to generate full url instead of using relative one's like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

According to laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset), the `asset` method automatically detects the request protocol and generates URL accordingly.

Now the application is not running on HTTPS,
I can use `secure_asset` for HTTPS URLs, but then it will stop running on HTTP and `localhost`.

I know there is something I'm missing and it can't be so hard to just migrate from HTTP to HTTPS using `laravel`

PS - `Cloudflare` is being used for serving `HTTPS` requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All answers given till now are correct but none solved my problem.

The main problem was my application was behind `CloudFlare`

Laravel detects a Request as secure or insecure by checking a HTTP header i.e. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']` which remains HTTP even the Request is HTTPS due to cloudflare.

CloudFlare sets a different header for the same i.e. `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']` Which must be checked to detect a request is secure or not

Following [this](http://www.code-examples.com/laravel-5-ssl-routes-behind-a-load-balancer/) article and making some changes to this I successfully managed to generate HTTPS URL without making any changes to previous application code.

Comment: I believe that enabling mod_cloudflare (if you're using apache) would have solved your issue without having to write any code.

Comment: That would have solved it for cloudflare but this solution is universal for all types of load balancers

Comment: Sorry, i thought the question was focused on cloudflare, as stated in the title.

Comment: Your url is not valid anymore... sad

Comment: URL is still working. IT might be your firewall settings

Comment: Chrome introduced a recent change that caused this problem for me and had a http redirect in the middle of the rest, which were all https. This solution in this post/the linked page did the trick. Since that site is down you can instead find it on the WayBackMachine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180423193212/http://www.code-examples.com/laravel-5-ssl-routes-behind-a-load-balancer/

Answer (score 1):

Accessing The Request
To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection, you should type-hint the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class on your controller constructor or method
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#request-information

instead of manually setting it through configs you could use Request::secure() to check, if the request is done over HTTPS

Comment: I already know i can i either do that or directrly use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']` to detect whether request is secure or not but i don't see how it will help the asset function to generate correct url

Answer (score 0):

According [laravel source](https://github.com/igorw/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L119), asset will generate protocol based on request info if you don't explicitly hint it to use http/https. So, you should not change anything here. That will switch to https once you start requesting it via secure connection.

Comment: As far as i know i have not changed it explicitly but can you please tell me from where i can verify it